# Vue.js Router Base Setting breaking links in Development Mode

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-cli

I have a simple `vue-cli` project that uses `vue-router`. With the default config everything works fine, but I need/want to change the router base to `/app/` which breaks all the links.

When I change the base of the router and run the development mode (`vue-cli-service serve`) I can access the root route but all the links are not working. The console throws a not found error when I click my Link to `/app/groups`:

```
app.js:460          GET http://localhost:8080/app/js/src_views_AssetGroupView_vue.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

**My router:**

```
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory('/app/'),
  routes
})
```

**My routes:**

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: HomeView
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'login',
    component: LoginView
  },
  {
    path: '/register',
    name: 'register',
    component: LoginView
  },
  {
    path: '/groups',
    name: 'groups',
    component: () => import('src/views/AssetGroupView.vue')
  }
]
```

**Versions:**

```
"vue": "^3.2.39",
"vue-router": "^4.1.5",
```

**My vue.config.js:**

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  // Used for Django Deployment in Build
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '/static/spa' : '', 
  outputDir: '../static/spa', 
  indexPath: '../../templates/index.html', 
})
```

I would expect that changing the base of the router would also work in `serve` mode but for some reasons all links try to request a non-existing resource.

I am a little lost why it works when I change the base to '' and it also works fine in development build. Any ideas how to fix this behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it out myself.

For some reason changing the router base path also changes the base path for the internal JS links from `js` to `app/js`.
So for the development mode one also has to change the `vue.config.js` `publicPath` variable. With the following `vue.config.js` it works.

```
[...]
module.exports = defineConfig({

  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '/static/spa' : '/app/',

[...]
```